# iPhone / Android Intents

Tags: android, iphone, android-intent

In Android Development, I can simply start another Android App with data from my own App using Intents.

For example: In my App, I have have typed some text, then click a button, another App of mine starts and displays that typed text from the other App.

Now the question: is this possible in iPhone Development? Can I start another App with data from my App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use URL Schemes, take a look on [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/)

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger another app by applying `URL Schemes` in both iPhone App. Parameters can be passed to other app.